# How to evaluate an algebraic function at a place of an algebraic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Given a field $K$ and an irreducible polynomial $f(x,y) \in K[x,y]$ that defines an algebraic curve, we can construct the maximal order $O$, consisting of all algebraic function with finite values at all finite points, and define a *place* as a prime ideal in $O$.

We need to distinguish between points (prime ideals in the coordinate ring $K[x,y] \bmod f$) and places (prime ideals in the maximal order $O$) in order to handle singularities, where there are multiple places at a single point.

For example, the curve $y^2 = x^3+x^2$ has a singularity at the origin; there are two places at a single point:

[image: implicit_plot(y^2-(x^3+x^2), (-2,2), (-2,2), axes=True)]

A function like $x/y$ can not be evaluated at the origin just by plugging in values for $x$ and $y$.  Not only do you get zero divided by zero, but the value is indeterminate because we need to specify which branch of the curve we're on, i.e, which *place*.  Once we've specified one of the two places/branches, we can then ask for the value of $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} x/y$.

We can do a lot of this calculation in Sage 9:

```
sage: K.<x> = FunctionField(QQbar); _.<Y> = K[]
sage: A.<y> = K.extension(Y^2-(x^3+x^2))
sage: OA=A.maximal_order()
sage: OA.basis()
(1, 1/x*y)
sage: OA.ideal(x,y)
Ideal (x) of Maximal order of Function field in y defined by y^2 - x^3 - x^2
sage: OA.ideal(x,y).factor()
(Ideal (1/x*y - 1) of Maximal order of Function field in y defined by y^2 - x^3 - x^2) * 
(Ideal (1/x*y + 1) of Maximal order of Function field in y defined by y^2 - x^3 - x^2)
```

This tells us:

1. The basis for the maximal order $O$ as a $K[x,y]$-module is $\{1,y/x\}$, i.e, $\{1,y/x\}$ is an *integral basis* for this curve, and all algebraic functions with finite values at all finite places can be written as $a+b(y/x)$ where $a,b \in K[x,y]$,
2. There's a singularity at the origin, since the ideal (in $O$) generated by $x$ and $y$ is not prime,
3. The prime factors of the ideal correspond to the two places of the curve at the origin, and
4. The value of $y/x$ is $1$ at the one place and $-1$ at the other.

So we can conclude that the value of $x/y$ is also $1$ at the place represented by `Ideal (1/x*y - 1)` and $-1$ at the place represented by `Ideal (1/x*y + 1)`.

My question: given the irreducible polynomial $f(x,y)$ and the generators of one of these prime ideals in $O$, how to compute the value of an arbitrary algebraic function like $x/y$?  The example I gave is easy, but how to do it in general?

An obvious way is to approach it as a limit, but I'm not even sure that I can guarantee that L'Hospital's rule always terminates here.  Also, I'm looking for a more algebraic approach.  Obviously, substituting in values for $x$ and $y$ works in some cases, but how do I deal with the cases where that produces $0/0$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's work in the situation where $K$ is algebraically closed. This is the "geometric" situation.

In this situation, for any place, i.e., nonzero prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $O$, the quotient ring $O/\mathfrak{p}$ is canonically isomorphic to $K$. (I've outlined the reason why in a postscript.)

For any $f\in O$, you can ask what the image of $f$ is in the quotient ring $O/\mathfrak{p}$. This is an element of $K$, because $O/\mathfrak{p}$ is canonically identified with $K$. And the value of $f$ at the place $\mathfrak{p}$ is simply the image of $f$ in $O/\mathfrak{p}\cong K$!

In your example, with $f = y/x$, the image of $f$ in $K[y/x]/(y/x - 1)$ is $1$ because $y/x-1=0$ in that ring, therefore $f=y/x=1$ in that ring. Meanwhile, the image of $f$ in $K[y/x]/(y/x+1)$ is $-1$, because $y/x+1=0$ in that ring, therefore $f=y/x = -1$ in that ring.

**Postscript:** The reason why $O/\mathfrak{p}$ is canonically isomorphic to $K$.

This is because the curve is one-dimensional, so $O$ is a [one-dimensional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull_dimension) ring, so $\mathfrak{p}$ is a maximal ideal, so $O/\mathfrak{p}$ is a field; and, $O$ is finitely generated as a $K$-algebra, so $O/\mathfrak{p}$ is also finitely generated as a $K$-algebra, and [Hilbert's Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_Nullstellensatz) tells us that a field that's a finitely generated algebra over an algebraically closed field $K$ is actually $K$. Thus $O/\mathfrak{p}\cong K$. The isomorphism is canonical because all the rings in sight contain $K$, so the canonical homomorphism from $O$ to $O/\mathfrak{p}$ amounts to a surjection onto the subring $K$.

Comment: OK, makes sense, but my question is how to actually compute that value for a generic rational function f, in particular an f that yields 0/0 if you just plug in values for x and y.

Comment: You can do it with Grobner bases. I'll add some info to the answer.

Comment: Oops, I started to make the edit but I don't have time now. Will try to circle back to this in the next few days.